# where does woocommerce store orders?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking in the sql db and I can see something that resembles orders inside wp_posts . However, I would expect them to be inside the tables beginning with wp_woocommerce.

Can anyone shed some light on this phenomenon?

Cheers

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In woocommerce orders are modelled as a [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) so they are stored in `wp_posts` as you found. See [WooCommerce taxonomies and post types](https://woocommerce.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/) for a list of the custom post types that woocommerce uses. Orders are stored as the type `shop_order`

Separate items within an Order are stored as separate records in the custom table [woocommerce_order_items](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description#table-woocommerce_order_items)

Comment: I was looking for _billing_address and fields like this, but I can see these references in the code are actually functions that are drawing data from several tables :/

Comment: `_billing_address` is in `wp_postmeta` as it is simply meta for the `order` post.

Comment: Omg, thank you, but wp dev is so tricky... Architecture? No, did not hear...

Answer (score 21):

**Updated plug-in version information 8/10/2018**

Orders are a custom post type. From WooCommerce [Post Types](https://woocommerce.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/):

> - Shop Order (shop_order)

Orders live in the `wp_posts` table (`post_type = 'shop_order'`). More data is available by looking up the order's post_id in the `wp_postmeta` table.

In addition, from the WooCommerce GitHub Wiki [Database Description](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description)

> - **woocommerce_order_items** – Stores line items which are associated with orders.
> - **woocommerce_order_itemmeta** – Stores meta data about order line items.

Currently the WordPress WooCommerce plug-in version is 3.4.x

Answer (score 5):

WooCommerce orders are "custom post" they are stored in "wp_posts" under "post_type" -> ""shop_order"

if you want to select shop orders with sql query you can do something like below.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'", ARRAY_A );
```

Comment: this does not include items - you also need 
wp_woocommerce_order_items
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta

Answer (score 3):

You can find them inside `wp_posts` table.

In PhpMyAdmin:

Click **wp_posts** table, then click SQL Tab and run the following query, assuming wp_posts is your table name:

`Select * from wp_posts where post_type='shop_order'`

Then you have all the data regarding woocommerce orders

click "Show all" checkbox

Search for "completed"  for completed orders

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
wp_woocommerce_order_items
wp_posts
```

Depending on the kind of data your looking for you have to look in diffrent places. If you have PHPMyAdmin try and find the data your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I recently restored the orders data manually and here is the table I found.

```
wp_posts //post_type = shop_order
wp_postmeta 
wp_woocommerce_order_items
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
```

Make sure your order_id/order_item_id reference is correct on postmeta and itemmeta.